# How to number the index with tocbibind and idxlayout?

Tags: numbering, indexing, tocbibind, idxlayout

I'm trying to number the index section in my document. If I use only `tocbibind` it works perfectly, but once I add `idxlayout`, it doesn't work. `idxlayout` doesn't have a `numindex` option like `tocbibind`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage[numindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[totoc]{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

Test\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How to add the number to the index section and keep `idxlayout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the load order of `tocbibind` and `idxlayout` won't work because both packages redefine the `theindex` environment, so whichever package is loaded later will disable the features of the former.

I didn't include an option to number the index in `idxlayout` because I regard it as bad from a typographic point of view. If you must, patch the internal `\ila@prologue` macro *and* remove the `totoc` option.

(Note: For the `book` and `report` standard  classes and for the `memoir` class, replace `\section*`/`\section` with `\chapter*`/`\chapter` in the example below. A different patching approach would be needed for the `KOMA-Script` classes.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage[numindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}% already loaded by `idxlayout`
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ila@prologue}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

Test\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```